report results to 4 decimal places when using add_ci function in gtsummary package
I am currently running the syntax below and am wondering whether it is possible to report the confidence intervals to 4 decimal places?
library(survey)
library(gtsummary)

data(api, package = "survey")
svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) |>
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = "both",
    include = c(api00, stype),
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) |>
  add_stat_label() |>
  add_ci(pattern = "{stat} (95% CI {ci})") |>
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") |>
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Survived**")


See https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/1141:
The answer adjusted accordingly to Daniel's comment :)
[...]
my_style <- label_style_number(digits = 4, scale = 100)

survey::svydesign(id = ~dnum, weights = ~pw, data = apiclus1, fpc = ~fpc) |>
  tbl_svysummary(
    by = "both",
    include = c(api00, stype),
    statistic = all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
  ) |>
  add_stat_label() |>
  add_ci(pattern = "{stat} (95% CI {ci})",
         style_fun = list(all_categorical() ~ my_style)
         ) |>
  modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**") |>
  modify_spanning_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**Survived**")




This is perfect! I would make two small changes, 1. I would use the scale=100 argument to multiply the proportions to the percent scale, 2. I would use label_style_number(digits = 4, scale = 100) instead of purrr::partial() just because it's a little easier on the eyes (･_･┐)

I believe there could be a bug somewhere in version 2.0.3 of the gtsummary package. I am having a variable with 47 levels and the syntax is taking hours running without success str(KEKR8CFL$v024)  dbl+lbl [1:19530] 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...  @ label       : chr "region"  @ format.stata: chr "%8.0g"  @ labels      : Named num [1:47] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:47] "mombasa" "kwale" "kilifi" "tana river" ...

@StephenOkiya, report the issue then: https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues
